# Disabling SystemKeys in C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a voice chat program (Discord) in the background that activates my microphone when I press a certain key. Whenever I have my C# WPF application opened, the voice chat program does not detect the key-press any more regardless of what key I bind it to. You would say the problem lies with the voice chat application but when I have Firefox or any other application opened its working just fine. Perhaps the problem lies with my WPF application? I created a new WPF project and the problem still occurred.

**Question**
Why are keystrokes not detected by other applications while my C# application is active?

Comment: Share the piece of code that binds your keystrokes please.

Comment: My application does not bind any keystrokes.

Comment: Does any other application other that `Discord` have that kind of behavior? Maybe, that application handle the keyboard in some weird ways... Try to find other application that use some global hotkey (maybe a screen capture application)

Comment: Yes I have tried another program just now and it has the exact same problem no matter what key I use.

Comment: Please share the code like, how you are activating your microphone when you press a certain key.

Comment: Its not my application thats activing the microphone, its another application thats not mine called Discord. I am merely trying to find out why my application is interfering with Discord or other applications and how it could be fixed.